# Docker - assigning ipv6 address in docker run

Tags: docker, ipv6, docker-network

I have a ipv6 subnet **(2001:637:407:201:db00::/78)** . From this I have used **2001:637:407:201:db03::/80**
for docker ipv6 address(defind this in daemon.json).
Now I am using  `docker run -d --ip6 2001:637:407:201:db00:cafe:5555/96 <image>`
The problem is that the container is taking its address from the docker subnet and not the one I have assigned during docker run.
Is there a way to assign this address to the container with the used docker network setting.

Comment: If this wasn't running in Docker, how (and why) would you assign an IPv6 address to a specific process?

Comment: You really do not want to use any networks other than `/64`. You will break some IPv6 features. You are being delegated something smaller than `/64` so you should use IPv6 Prefix Delegation to assign `/64` networks from that. The only exception would be `/127` for point-to-point networks, an `/128` for loopback addresses.

Comment: The solution to this which worked for me was to create a new network with subnet 2001:637:407:201:db03:cafe::/96 and attached my container to it. Ofcourse with the desired address with a --ip6 flag assigned to it.